# Add MPMoviePlayerController's view to a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to add `MPMoviePlayerController` to a `UIView`.
first, I put a view in xib file, named youTubeView. youtubePlayer is the `MPMoviePlayerController`.

```
[youtubePlayer.view setFrame:youTubeView.frame];
[youTubeView addSubview:youtubePlayer.view];
[youtubePlayer play];
```

I want the view of youtubePlayer overlay on youTubeView. but the view of youtubePlayer goes wide, it just overlay a part of youTubeView. why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
[youtubePlayer.view setFrame:youTubeView.bounds];
[youTubeView addSubview:youtubePlayer.view];
[youtubePlayer play];
```

Comment: I know it now, this is the different define about bounds and frames.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the scaling mode for the movie like this `youtubePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;`

This will solve your problem.

Happy Coding:)