# How to get a video to play in UIWebView (video is in a ALAsset group)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiwebview, alasset

Okay maybe the headline is somehow disturbing, I hope to state this so you can understand my problem.
So I have a scrollview which has paging enabled. I want to build something like iOS Photo App.
I load the photos and videos which are on the device via ALAsset and store them in a group.
Now i want to present each object on a separate subview of the scrollview.
For the pictures it is working fine. But for videos I cant make it work.
Here is what i did and what did not work:
First:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<html><head><style></style></head><body>\
<video id='video_with_controls' width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" controls>\
<source src='%@' type='video/MOV'/></video><ul>\
</body></html>", self.mainScrollView.frame.size.width, self.mainScrollView.frame.size.height, [assetRepresentation url]];
[webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

then:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<video controls> <source src=\"%@\"> </video>", [assetRepresentation url];
[webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Also I tried to store it in NSData first and then load it from there, but that causes memory problems and wont work.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Edit: As I think UIWebView is the thing that matches the iOS App visually at most, I want to use this and not for example the MPMoviePlayer .. if I am wrong there I would be glad to know how / what else looks like the original App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the video url is local thats why its not working in UiWebView

so the solution would be this:
in delegate method webviewdidstartload,set up MPmovieplayer controller to play inside a UiView and yes it will look like original app as you will be playing it in a view

something like this:

[Add MPMoviePlayerController's view to a UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392870/add-mpmovieplayercontrollers-view-to-a-uiview)

Comment: I will test this now, although I have problems right now because the delegate method is not called. I set myself to <UIWebViewDelegate> but it does not get into the method webviewdidstartload ..  this should be called right after I created the webview variable?!

Comment: set webview.delegate = self;

Comment: I did this already  
    @interface SCImagesViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate>  
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
                [webView setDelegate:self];
                [webView setFrame:frame];

Comment: okay i figured that out, i just call [webView loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil], then the delegatemethod gets called. Got some problems with mpmediaplayer, gonna figure that out and come back when i got more problems (hope i dont come back :P). So thanks a lot for now!

Answer (score 0):

When you movie file is located locale you must set the baseURL to your MainBundle and put the full path in the "src"-tag.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but the video is not in the bundle, i get the videos and photos which are on the device.